# Set the application badge number in ios 9

Tags: ios, ios9, badge

I'd used

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5;
```

for setting application badge number. It's not working in ios 9 alone.

Can anyone suggest why?

I tried,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:5];
```

Comment: where / in which method you tried this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I used this in several places in my project. It's working fine in ios 8.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I need to change the badge number not in appdelegate.m, in some other viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Hi You need to register UIUserNotificationSettings like this

```
UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
```

Comment: without notifications, I'm setting badge number to my app icon. so no need to register notification settings

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:5];
 Use this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions this works fine

Comment: yes i have tried now. I got badge icon number whatever is set.

Comment: I just created a sample app and, paste that line in did finsh launch, it's not showing any badge count in the app icon, pl check this [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8KcdI.png)

Answer (score 5):

> Registering for Notification Types in iOS
>
> In iOS 8 and later, apps that use either local or remote notifications
>   must register the types of notifications they intend to deliver. The
>   system then gives the user the ability to limit the types of
>   notifications your app displays. The system does not badge icons,
>   display alert messages, or play alert sounds if any of these
>   notification types are not enabled for your app, even if they are
>   specified in the notification payload.
>   Link: [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)
>
> @property(nonatomic) NSInteger applicationIconBadgeNumber;  // set to 0 to hide. default is 0. In iOS 8.0 and later, your application must register for user notifications using -[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:] before being able to set the icon badge.

So I think you must register badges for change number notification.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, registered and tried, but no luck.

Comment: My app is already having push notif functions, it's working fine in ios 8, the issue is in ios 9.

Comment: I just test with iOS 9. I register:
 `UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;`
`UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];`
      ~  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];~

and I set: 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:5];

Comment: now I too got it. Ok if want to set badge number in somewhere else in the project means, what should I do?

Comment: Just call: 

 `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:5];` Change 5 to number you want.

Comment: it's working for new projects created in xcode 7.0, but my older project running in xcode 7, the badge number is not setting.

Comment: Can you let me see your code for register notificaiton? And can you check your app setting on setting of iOS?

Answer (score 4):

It works perfectly like this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;
```

I tried in Xcode 7.2, iOS 9.2, iPhone 6s Plus.

Answer (score 1):

Set it in you `Appdelegate.m` File in `didFinishLaunching` method...

`application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5.`

and change your current date to after 2 days and restart Your `iPhone`.. and test again. It should be working fine.

[image]

Comment: Since iOS 8 this does not work anymore without asking the user for permission to change the app icon badge.