# how to get fired local notification in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to get already fired local notification from notification panel so that I can manage application badge value.

Here is my code so far:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    if(application.applicationIconBadgeNumber < localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber){
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber;
    }else {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber--;
    }
}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33339931/5362916

Answer (score 0):

notification.fireDate = "Your Date";

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, particularly since `NSNotification.fireDate` is an `NSDate` not a `String`.

Comment: "Your Date " mean the date from picker you selected @DavidBerry