# How to disable application badge completely using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, push-notification

The user can disable an app from showing the badges from push notifications. How can this be done pragmatically? So far I have only found solutions where the badges are cleared when an app comes to the foreground. I am looking for a solution that would work regardless of whether the app is in the foreground, background or not launched at all.

I tried setting applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 in appDidFinishLaunching and that didn't work.

Comment: Did you register UIUserNotificationSettings? Maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/33339931/7340034

Comment: Yes and it works - I can show badge, but I want to completely disable it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it in applicationDidBecomeActive?. If the app is running in the background, appDidFinishLaunching will not be called

Comment: Yes. You still see the badge until you open the app.